# MS Access linking a table to an SSMS View

Tags: vba, ms-access, ssms

I am trying to create a dsnless connection to an SSMS view. I was able to connect to a few tables, just not quite sure how to get a specific view instead. This is my function to connect to the database. I only call this and pass through the variables needed.

```
Function AttachDSNLessTable(stLocalTableName As String, stRemoteTableName As String, stServer As String, stDatabase As String, Optional stUsername As String, Optional stPassword As String)
On Error GoTo AttachDSNLessTable_Err
Dim td As TableDef
Dim stConnect As String

For Each td In CurrentDb.TableDefs
    If td.Name = stLocalTableName Then
        CurrentDb.TableDefs.Delete stLocalTableName
    End If
Next

If Len(stUsername) = 0 Then
    '//Use trusted authentication if stUsername is not supplied.
    stConnect = "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=" & stServer & ";DATABASE=" & stDatabase & ";Trusted_Connection=Yes"
Else
    '//WARNING: This will save the username and the password with the linked table information.
    stConnect = "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=" & stServer & ";DATABASE=" & stDatabase & ";UID=" & stUsername & ";PWD=" & stPassword
End If
Set td = CurrentDb.CreateTableDef(stLocalTableName, dbAttachSavePWD, stRemoteTableName, stConnect)
CurrentDb.TableDefs.Append td
AttachDSNLessTable = True
MsgBox "New table created."
Exit Function

AttachDSNLessTable_Err:

AttachDSNLessTable = False
MsgBox "AttachDSNLessTable encountered an unexpected error: " & Err.Description

End Function
```

I'm calling this method with a button.

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()

Dim td As TableDef
Dim stConnect As String
Call AttachDSNLessTable("Order_Tracking_Tool", "Order_Tracking_Tool", "TestingServer", "TestDB", "TESTuser", "TESTpswd") 
End Sub
```

Comment: Show what you've tried. There shouldn't be any difference between linking to a table  and linking to a view if you do it through VBA.

Comment: I used the CreateTableDef method here. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/892490/how-to-create-a-dsn-less-connection-to-sql-server-for-linked-tables-in

Comment: Eh.. And did you try passing that the name of the view as the remote table name? Did it fail? If so, what was the error message?

Comment: The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'Order_Tracking_Tool'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'Order_Tracking_Tool' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator.

Comment: I ran it the same way I did with the table, just changed the name from the table to the view. Actual name of the view is dbo.Order_Tracking_Tool

Comment: Please try to provide a [mcve], include the exact arguments passed in the question, and include information like default schema (you do need to include the schema in the view name if it's non-default), and include the code used in the question (that Microsoft page might get moved or deleted, Microsoft has done so in the past).

Comment: I have added the actual code to the question.

Comment: But not the arguments you're passing to it...

Comment: added new method

Comment: Try connecting to the database in SSMS using the login and password you're using in the call to AttachDSNLessTable to see if the view shows up in the object explorer. It may be the SQL login being used lacks permissions to the view.

Comment: I've tried a few different access' and none of them seem to work. Although they are all valid.

Comment: Try using all of your logins in SSMS. Process of elimination. First, verify your login has permissions to the view.

Comment: Try manual linking to the one view. So use the ODBC manager launched from Access. Manual link the table. If the manual process works, then your code will not. Of course if you can't link to the table using the Access UI, then code is NEVER going to work. So first manual try linking the table without using code. If that works, then (and ONLY then) try you code again.